# Difference between adding MIME types in IIS via Websites vs Local Computer?

Tags: iis-6, mime, iis

What is the difference between adding MIME types in these 2 different situations?

When in IIS 6 manager...

1. Right click on the computer name (local computer) > properties > mime types
2. Right click on the "Web sites" folder > properties > http headers > mime types

I'm guessing that perhaps option 1 adds MIME types for FTP also? However if that were true i'd expect to be able to add MIME types specifically in the properties of FTP (and not just websites).

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that setting it at the "local computer" level sets it for all sites, and it cannot be removed, except for at the global level.

Setting it at the "web sites" level will **copy** the setting into each website (and new sites as they are created) allowing you to selectively remove the global setting on a site-by-site basis if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but please let me reiterate... it's not the website itself that I am intersted in, but the "Web sites" folder. i.e the "Web sites" folder that contains all the websites.

Comment: @Alex: sorry about that, don't know how I screwed that up. I fixed the answer so that it actually answers your question now. Still no FTP MIME types though.